# Postgresql put strings inside quotes with array_to_string

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, string-aggregation

In select I have used array_to_string like this (example)

```
array_to_string(array_agg(tag_name),';') tag_names
```

I got resulting string `"tag1;tag2;tag3;..."` but I would like to get resulting string as `"'tag1';'tag2';'tag3';..."`.

How can I do this in Postgres?

Comment: `array_to_string(array_agg(...))`  can be simplified to to `string_agg()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the functions [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) and [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) with the `%L` placeholder, which quotes the argument value as an SQL literal.

```sql
with my_table(tag_name) as (
values 
    ('tag1'),
    ('tag2'),
    ('tag3')
)

select string_agg(format('%L', tag_name), ';' order by tag_name) tag_names
from my_table;

      tag_names       
----------------------
 'tag1';'tag2';'tag3'
(1 row)
```

Alternatively, `format('%L', tag_name)` may be replaced with `quote_nullable(tag_name)`.

Answer (score 1):

Or your can use `unnest`, `format`, `array_agg` and `array_to_string` in one request like this :

```
select array_to_string(t.tag, ',')  
from (  
    select array_agg(format('%L', t.tag)) as tag  
    from (  
        select unnest(tag_name) as tag  
    ) t  
) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use

```
array_to_string(array_agg(''''||tag_name||''''),';') tag_names
```

or even simpler (thanks for the commenting :) )

```
string_agg(''''||tag_name||''''),';') tag_names
```

**Note:**

> When dealing with multiple-argument aggregate functions, note that the
>   ORDER BY clause goes after all the aggregate arguments. For example,
>   write this:
>
> SELECT string_agg(a, ',' ORDER BY a) FROM table;
>
> not this:
>
> SELECT string_agg(a ORDER BY a, ',') FROM table;  -- incorrect

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES

Comment: The alternate thing here should be the string concatenation, you should still be using string_agg rather than array_to_string(array_agg())

Comment: @eurotrash Thank you:)!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string_agg()` function with `'''; '''` so it will be like

```
SELECT string_agg(tag_name, '''; ''') from my_table
```